# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DELETE" when expecting one of the following: ( - + case mod new not null select with <an identifier>

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, cursor

I am trying to create stored procedure using Cursor for returning list of data as an output parameter.
***Error(9,5): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DELETE" when expecting one of the following:     ( - + case mod new not null select with***

Here is my procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DELETE_CUSTOMER 
(
    C_id IN NUMBER,
    DELETE_CURSOR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR 
)
AS  
BEGIN
    OPEN DELETE_CURSOR For
    Delete FROM CUSTOMER WHERE ID = C_id;

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no `DELETE FROM ...` available, only `SELECT FROM ...`. Also, there's no `==` either.

Fixed:

```
open delete_cursor for
  select * from customer where id = c_id;
```

Once you fetch data into cursor, you can do whatever you want with it; you'd probably want to delete rows that satisfy condition you put into the `WHERE` clause.

---

If you must use a cursor (educational purposes, I presume), then

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DELETE_CUSTOMER (C_id IN NUMBER)
AS
BEGIN
   FOR cur_r IN (SELECT id
                   FROM customer
                  WHERE id = c_id)
   LOOP
      DELETE FROM customer
            WHERE id = cur_r.id;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks, but one more question, by using select statement we can select data, please guide what will be the proper syntax to delete any record based on ID.

Comment: `delete from customer where id = c_id` is the simplest option. You don't need a (ref) cursor to do that.

Comment: Means there is no way to delete data using (ref) Cursor ?? because in my task it is compulsory to use cursor.

Comment: If it must be a cursor, then you could use code I posted at the bottom of my answer. Have a look.